# How to use jQuery bind on custom event for functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

first I want to thank you guys, long time lurker on stackoverflow and found a lot of answers to my questions, but I got a question which I cannot seem to find an answer.

How do you bind an ajax loaded content that has an onclick function that contains a parameter, so when the link is clicked, it activates the show showStudent(id) function.

**Background**

I have a page which loads ajax content, example of content below

```
<div class="students">
    <p>Student 1 <a onclick="showStudent('14')">View Here</a></p>
    <p>Student 2 <a onclick="showStudent('16')">View Here</a></p>
    <p>Student 3 <a onclick="showStudent('22')">View Here</a></p>
    <p>Student 4 <a onclick="showStudent('66')">View Here</a></p>
</div>
```

The javascript for showStudent is

```
function showStudent(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

I have already created a jQuery bind function to make it visually appealing

```
jQuery(document).bind('m-ajax-after', function () {
    previewInit();
});

function previewIt() { //code }
```

So how do i reinitialize showStudent(id) for the ajax content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, showStudent(id) works within the ajax response. What lead me to raise this question was an error within the showStudents(id) function that caused me to raise thsi question.